# AngularJs Server Node js /get

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js

Hello I have for this moment a fake backend with httpbackend in my angular Project. But I want to transfer my fake backend in a server node js but I don't know.

So For this moment I have this :

```
var express = require('express')
    , path = require('path')
    , fs = require('fs')
    , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    , morgan = require('morgan');

var apps = express();
var staticRoot = __dirname + '/';
apps.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));
apps.use(express.static(staticRoot));
apps.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
apps.use(bodyParser.json());
apps.use(morgan('dev'));

apps.use(function (req, res, next) {

    var ext = path.extname(req.path);
    if (ext !== '') {
        return next();
    }
});



apps.get('/getTpl', function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(JSON.parse(["tp1", "tp2", "tp3", "tp4", "tp5", "tp6", "tp7"]));

});

apps.listen(apps.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('serveur en route, port : ', apps.get('port'));
});
```

My controller :

```
 ctrl.tpls = [];
        ctrl.tplJson = undefined;

        diapoService.getTpl().then(function (response) {
            ctrl.tpls = JSON.stringify(response.data);
            console.log(response.data);
        });

   function getTpl() {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET'
                , url: '/getTpl'
            });
```

I want to send my array in my select but my select is empty why ? please

Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: Instead of res.writeHead and res.end use res.json(JSON.parse(....));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change this function:

```
apps.get('/getTpl', function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).json(["tp1", "tp2", "tp3", "tp4", "tp5", "tp6", "tp7"]);
});
```

Additionally I do not use Angular, but I don't think that you have to stringify the response:

```
diapoService.getTpl().then(function (response) {
    ctrl.tpls = JSON.stringify(response.data); // <- Is this necessary?
    console.log(response.data);
});
```